# Export a table and zip with password

Tags: sql-server, export, compression, sql-clr, ole-automation

I would like, from TSQL, to use a view to extract data from a table, output it with BCP, then use non 3rd party tools to ZIP it with a password and AES encryption. Optionnally, I could use a 3rd party tool that doesn't require a local installation (standalone EXE on a network drive for example).

I tried using `sp_OA*`, but found [this post saying they were buggy, memory-leaky and deprecated features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052815/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure-sys-sp-oacreate-of-component-ole-autom). So I am looking for alternatives, if there are any. Google searches all came back to the same solutions: 7zip, Winrar, or `sp_OA*`.

I don't want the code, just the name of the features or methods that could help me, so I would know what to search for.

MSSQL2008 and up. Can be a Powershell solution. Not SSIS if possible. For the record, it's to daily update a software with current data, as it doesn't have direct access to the source.

If 7zip is the best/only way to go, I'll have a ton of paperwork to fill in and meetings to attend to justify installing non-database software on a SQL server. :-)

Comment: Why do you want to do all of this stuff *from T-SQL*? [This sounds like someone else's job](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/system-configuration/stop-making-sql-server-dirty-work).

Comment: No particular reason. It is part of a larger process already in SQL, it leverages the SQLAgent's timer and all my custom error notification processes, and I have it under my nose daily, whereas I don't often go check on the Windows Scheduler of the servers. But I can be flexible depending on the possible options.

Comment: What version of windows server are you using ? I would suggest to look into `BCP OUT in Native format` --> This is non human readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, stay away from the `sp_OA*` OLE Automation procedures.

If you want  / need to handle this purely within SQL Server then you can do so using SQLCLR, which replaces the `sp_OA*` OLE Automation procedures. And if you aren't using `xp_cmdshell` for anything else, then no need to enable it just for this (although to be fair, if using SQL Agent, then a CMD step would be able to execute BCP and/or 7zip without the need for enabling `xp_cmdshell`).

With SQLCLR you can:

- do the export from within T-SQL as well and not need to mess with BCP which is an external process (see [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)).
- zip the file, as a separate step, since. NET has methods to gzip and gunzip (see [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)).
- encrypt with a password (see [RijndaelManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) and [AesManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)). While you did specify AES, the MSDN documentation for AesManaged states:

  > The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same way as the RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to 128 bits and does not allow feedback modes.

  The difference is if you are using SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2. Those versions are limited to using .NET 3.5, and the MSDN documentation for `AesManaged` (for that version) states that it has a Host Protection Attribute (HPA) which means that any assembly using that class has to be marked as `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`, whereas `RijndaelManaged` does not have that issue and can be used in an `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` assembly. However, it seems that the documentation for `AesManaged` shows that, starting in .NET Framework version 4.0 (SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016 use .NET Framework 4.0 and newer--currently up to 4.6), the note about the HPA has been removed. Even if `UNSAFE` is acceptable, please note that the specific HPA is [MayLeakOnAbort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.hostprotectionattribute.mayleakonabort(v=vs.90).aspx), which means "might leak memory if the operation is terminated".

In this setup, the password is part of the encryption, not the compression. Hence you either have a zip file containing an encrypted file, or you have an encrypted file containing the zip file. The former method gives you a file that can be unzipped by anyone but then only read by someone with the correct password. The latter method requires knowing the password to get the compressed file, and also allows for better compression since the compression will be done on a text file  (with a greater likelihood of compressible patterns).

While I have not implemented the encryption algorithms yet, I have coded both the file export (of any random query) and GZip/GZunzip in SQLCLR and can state that they do run efficiently, or at least can be made to be efficient (and can also be made to be inefficient). By this I mean I have used them to extract queries producing 5 GB text files, and GZipping those 5 GB text files, and memory was never adversely affected since both operations are streamed. Please note that the .NET-provided GZipStream class does not support the Zip64 format, and so is limited to 4 GB of source data.

For anyone who is interested in pre-built SQLCLR functions to do the extract and compression (the ones I mentioned above), they are available in the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library (which I am the author of). Please note that:

- while there is a Free version of SQL#, the two objects mentioned here, **DB_BulkExport** and **File_GZip**, are only available in the Full version.
- in order to overcome the 4 GB limitation of the `GZipStream` class, I had to incorporate a 3rd-party library that does support Zip64.
- soon enough there will be functions to handle file encryption and decryption via Rijndael (available for SQL Server 2005 - 2016 at least) and Aes (available for SQL Server 2012 - 2016 at least).

Comment: Thanks everyone that dropped in their input. Special kudos to @srutzky for a glance into CLR that I hadn't even considered.

After some more discussions with colleagues, it seems a standalone version of 7zip (the EXE and a DLL) were already placed on the server. So I am free to use it after all!

I will accept srutzky's answer, as it is probably the next option I would have looked into if I still had to solve the problem.

Thanks again all!

Answer (score 0):

I do that using `xp_cmdshell`. You can export data from SQL job and then you can zip using that stored procedure. The best way is to run a bat file for zip.

REMARK: to use that sp you need that it is allowed (on SQL Server level) and you must have permissions to run it.

Comment: Extracting some data from SQL server is a horrible justification to enable xp_cmdshell. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2008/01/10/xp-cmdshell.aspx

Comment: I agree @Dave, but I need to make zip of backups and I think that this is far better then `sp_OA*`